# .NET Core & Entity Framework Core - loop referencing

Tags: json, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 with Entity Framework Core.

When I ask for this `Get` method:

```
// GET: api/Posts
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Post>>> GetPosts()
{
    return await _context.Posts.Include(u => u.Usuario)
                                .Include(p => p.Producto)
                                .ThenInclude(m => m.Modulos)
                                .ThenInclude(p => p.Procesos)
                                .ToListAsync();
}
```

The API return this loop referencing:

```
[{"id":8,"titulo":"Prueba Quill","fecha":"2020-10-13T00:00:00","ism":123,"alcance":0,"votos":null,"usuario":{"id":2,"nombre":"Juan H","apellido":"N","codigo":"jn","password":"jn","estado":0,"posts":[]},"producto":{"id":16,"nombre":"ERP - Agilis","posts":[],"modulos":[{"id":60,"nombre":"Engine Basico","posts":[],"procesos":[{"id":96,"nombre":"General","posts":[]}]}]},"modulo":{"id":60,"nombre":"Engine Basico","posts":[],"producto":{"id":16,"nombre":"ERP - Agilis","posts":[],"modulos":[]},"procesos":[{"id":96,"nombre":"General","posts":[]}]},"proceso":{"id":96,"nombre":"General","posts":[],"modulo":{"id":60,"nombre":"Engine Basico","posts":[],"producto":{"id":16,"nombre":"ERP - Agilis","posts":[],"modulos":[]},"procesos":[]}},"texto":"some text..."}]
```

The fact is that I have already set the `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` in the `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
         {
             options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
         });
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? I don't see loop there. What you have is `A->B->C->D`, `A->C` and `A->D`. it can be called a loop if you have following: `A->B->A->B...`

Comment: Add the model classes as well in the question.